# bash script to replace spaces in html

Tags: python, html, linux, bash, sed

I need a linux bash script that can replace the spaces in name="this is a test".

example:

```
<input name="this is a test" id="testing 1 2 3" />
```

would change to this:

```
<input name="thisisatest" id="testing 1 2 3" />
```

EDIT: The script must be able to match anything between the double quotes.  It could be this:

```
<input name="THIS STRING WILL VARY" id="testing 1 2 3" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Would a Python solution be a valid answer - it's tagged as such, but you're asking for a bash script...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Python - to take an HTML file, and remove spaces from `input` tags that have a `name` attribute equal to `this is a test`, you can use:

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('input') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fin.read())
    for tag in soup.find_all('input', {'name': 'this is a test'}):
        tag['name'] = tag['name'].replace(' ', '')
    fout.write(str(soup))
```

In response to:

> I forgot to say that the string "this is a test" can be anything

You can just filter out all `input` tags that have a `name` attribute and apply whatever logic you want - the below will remove spaces from any name attribute:

```
for tag in soup.find_all('input', {'name': True}):
    tag['name'] = tag['name'].replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: I forgot to say that the string "this is a test" can be anything.

Comment: @user2602373 updated to show how to find and replace any input tag with a name attribute - put whatever logic you want in it...

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> name = 'this is a test'
>>> ''.join(name.split())
'thisisatest'
```

Comment: Doesn't explain how to replace in a file, but what's wrong with `name.replace(' ','')` anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
foo='<input name="this is a test" id="testing 1 2 3" />'
echo $foo | sed 's/this is a test/thisisatest/'
```

If you want to do this in a file and save it, you can do this:

```
sed 's/this is a test/thisisatest/' filename > filename
```

Comment: I forgot to say that the string "this is a test" can be anything.  It must match name="THIS TEXT CAN VARY"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awk one-liner

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS=OFS="\""} 
    {for (f=2; f<=NF; f++) if ($(f-1) ~ /name=$/) gsub(/ /, "", $f)} 
    1
' file
```

It uses double quotes as the field separator. A quoted string will therefore be an odd-numbered field.